# Understanding ssh automatic login and security problems

Tags: linux, ssh, security, private-key

I have generated a pair of private/public ssh keys (on Linux) and they are now in my `.ssh` folder.

I have copied my ssh id (`ssh-copy-id`) to a remote machine to which I want to connect without typing my key all the time.

After copying my ssh id, I have been able to connect to the machine without entering the password, and I have double checked, in `.ssh/authorized_keys`, that the only authorized public key is the one I have just copied (which is fine).

However, I have seen two problems:

**First**, for some reason, `ssh-copy-id` has copied my private key to that machine as well. I have deleted it because it seems to be a big security whole spreading your private key over other machines. Is this correct?

**Second**, I have seen that my public key is now written in `.ssh/authorized_keys`. This file's permissions are configured so only my user can read it (`-rw-------`). Still, if someone managed to access this content, he/she could access my remote computer without password, is this correct? I have seen that, in my local computer, this file has been generated with permissions that would allow any other user (logged in the machine) to read it. Isn't this a security hole? Should I change the permissions so only my user can read the file's content?

**Last**, which key is actually used to very my identity when connecting to the remote machine, the private one or the public one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ssh-copy-id` should only have copied the public key to `authorized_keys`, it should not have copied your private key. Are you sure you didn't manually copy anything else to the remote machine or had you also generated a set of keys on the remote machine (with the default file names)?
2. No, only if somebody can write they own public key to `authorized_keys` can they access that machine as you. Being able to read that file doesn't allow access to any other machine.
3. Both. Your private key is used to sign a challenge presented by the remote machine when you try to connect, this is then checked on the remote machine using the public key to prove it was your private key that signed the challenge.

I suggest you go have a look at how asymmetric encryption works.